# ValueError: I/O operation on closed file, while excecuting the lines

Tags: python, io

I am getting "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file" while operating the code, I tried but failed, could you please make it error-free

```
Input
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP XXX.XX.XX.X:57079;branch=94tsjam66cmay5bpswyfta0nebw34zhfctjuuge2baevikbk03opf15t6wvovnb82mjih3v;received=IP;rport=57079
From: "IP" <sip:IP@IP>;tag=0c26cd11
To: <sip:XXXXXX@XXX.XX.XX.XXX>;tag=as3a5a21bf
Call-ID: 88c218486f66a6aa214d483d988dfa9c
CSeq: 2 INVITE
Server: Asterisk
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, PRACK, MESSAGE
Supported: replaces, timer
Reason: Q.850;cause=21
Content-Length: 0
```

My code (default)

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict
import io

with io.open('file location','r') as f:

    text = f.readlines()
result = []
blocks = [ txt.split('\n\n\n') for txt in f ]

# print(blocks)

print(len(blocks))
IP_add_dict_list = defaultdict(list)
IP_add_dict_set = defaultdict(set)

for block in blocks:
    if ("CSeq: 1 INVITE" or "CSeq: 1 INVITE") in block:
        caller = r";received=\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3};"
        x = re.search(caller, block)
        callerIP = x.group()
        callerIP = callerIP[10:-1]
        to = r"To: <sip:(\d|[+]|(0-9))*@"
        y = re.search(to, block)
        toSip = y.group()
        toSip = toSip[9:-1]
        call = (callerIP, toSip)
        result.append(call)
        # print(callerIP, toSip)
        IP_add_dict_list[callerIP].append(toSip)
        IP_add_dict_set[callerIP].add(toSip)
print(IP_add_dict_list)
print("---------------")
print(IP_add_dict_set)
```

So , if i run it it gives me this error :

```
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

Comment: I suggest using an actual parsing lib for pcap files instead of treating it as a random binary file, such as scapy or pyshark.

Comment: @SuperStormer I checked via both method, but I am still unable to get the desired result., I need the Call ID number and Received Ip address every time it hits INVITE.

Comment: Can you post a hexdump of your pcap file? If you're on windows, you can use [powershell](https://superuser.com/a/1247756/952376)

Comment: @SuperStormer can you suggest some other ideas